# adding default icon in html notifications on error

Tags: javascript, html, notifications, web-notifications

I am using HTML5 notifications to create notifications for my web application.

I am using options as follows for the notification code :-

```
var options = {
            body: text,
            icon: encodeParams("/photo?num="+snum+"&id="+cnum),
            dir : "auto",
            tag : cnum,
        };
```

All text, snum and cnum are defined.

The icon is retrieved from the server and works fine.
However if the icon doesn't exist at the server :: the notification icon goes blank.

I want to add a default icon if the image is not found.

Can someone help regarding this without an extra HTTP call ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to make the server side send a default if the requested one is not found

Alternatively, preload all images using javascript, so you can detect the images that don't exist, then replace them with default images when show the notification - however, this may violate your "no extra http calls" conditional

Comment: perhaps my language is inelegant, but it is an answer

Comment: I see where the confusion may have been with my "have the server ... " it sounded like a broken english question rather than a bad english suggestion :p

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Base64 CSS background image on the image element, this way if the image request fails your default image will be there from the start. This will also take care of the extra HTTP request.

For instance:

```
img {
   background-image: url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOVSKudfOulrSOp3WOyDZu6QdvCchPGolfO0o/XBs/fNwfjZ0frl3/zy7////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAkAABAALAAAAAAQABAAAAVVICSOZGlCQAosJ6mu7fiyZeKqNKToQGDsM8hBADgUXoGAiqhSvp5QAnQKGIgUhwFUYLCVDFCrKUE1lBavAViFIDlTImbKC5Gm2hB0SlBCBMQiB0UjIQA7);
   background-size: contain;
}
```

`<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/000000">`

See https://css-tricks.com/data-uris/ for more info on base64 image encoding and its use in CSS